# Git diff for a specific file using Simple Git in Node.js returns the entire diff

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, diff

I'm currently using the Simple Git library in my Node.js project to get the diff of a specific file. However, when I use the git.diff(["--"], file) function, it returns the entire diff instead of the diff for the specific file. Here's the code snippet:

```js
GitControl.prototype.diff = async function (git, param, callback) {
  const file = param[0];
  console.log(file);
  try {
    const result = await git.diff(["--"], file);
    callback(null, JSON.stringify({ success: true, diffText: result }));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`GIT CONTROL DIFF ERROR OCCUR: ${err}`);
    callback(err, JSON.stringify({ success: false, error: err.message }));
  }
};
```

When I run the equivalent command in the terminal (git diff -- bin/Source/MainView.js), it works as expected and returns the diff for the specified file.

I've confirmed that the file variable contains the correct file path (e.g., "bin/Source/View/qnaView.js").

[image]

Is there a difference between the git diff --  command in the terminal and the git.diff(["--"], file) function in Simple Git? If so, how can I modify my code to get the diff for a specific file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const result = await git.diff(["--", file]);
```

simply solved